# Разработка интернет-магазина на РНР

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Скажите, пожалуйста, с чего мне следует начинать при разработке магазина и, пожалуйста, подробней.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Начать следует с **логики**! В жизни очень полезная штука!

Answer (score 1):

Ну и вопрос... Начни с изучения php и mysql. для javascript и jq и так полно скриптов на любой вкус. Можно начать читать книги или ходить на платные курсы, что не менее полезно. Но мне как не странно больше всего пригодился уже готовый скрипт, который в последствии я начал дописывать, встречая для себя разные трудности я просто пытался сделать на подобии того, что у меня имелось на данный момент, то есть если взять уже готовый скрипт и подстраивать его под себя, то изучение и полезный эффект для Вас будет больше нежели Вы будите изучать все с самого начала. Если есть время то можно и поизучать функции, но то как функции описаны на многочисленных сайтах ставят под сомнение вообще реальность изучения языка.

Answer (score 1):

Именно для разработки или открытия?  
Если первое, то с изучения php, mySQL и HTML естественно (куда ж без HTML). 
Знание PHPMyAdmin или хотя бы какой-нибудь CMS. 
Умение развёртывание проекта на хостинге.     А вообще грамотные люди начинают с тех.задания (проект сайта интернет-магазина).      Где описывается и интерфейс и движек (или CMS), на котором он будет гонять.

Answer (score 0):

начать нужно с:

1. с пользователей
2. каталог
3. корзина

это минимум, хотя я думаю если вы спрашиваете теорию значит, у вас нет идей по реализации магазина, исходя из этого вывода советую вам воспользоватся готовыми решениями.

Answer (score 0):

Битрикс: Малый бизнес, там все готово уже. Но платный и очень не советую, если нужно будет делать изменения в логике работы магазина или каталога.

Если же нужен стандартный каталог с корзиной, то подойдет.

Как вариант, есть версия Старт, там можно сделать тоже самое, но вручную, получится более гибкое решение. Стоит в 5 раз дешевле чем Малый бизнес.

Сам делал магазины на нем и очень не люблю его, но вдруг кому-то нравится как готовое решение.

Answer (score -1):

посмотрите уже готовый, например, Virtuemart под JOOMLA

Comment: Не советуйте это больше никому кроме своих возможных клиентов!!!

Comment: бгггггг +1

Comment: +адын к комменту @parmervan